# Following a Javascript link when scraping from a remote site using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, screen-scraping

Given remote page:

http://example.com/paged_list.aspx

which uses a Javascript function call to display several pages of tabular data:

javascript: show_page(1)
javascript: show_page(2)

and so on. Users click on the page links to display each page, which triggers a reload but with no query string, ie the URI remains the same.

In scraping this site, it would be useful to have a way to obtain subsequent pages but there is no obvious way to specify a page number in the request (passed to file_get_contents()).

Is there any way to:

1. Open a remote web address.
2. Call a known javascript function at that address.
3. Return the results?

Comment: Cant you find the source of the pages if there imbedded in JS? Find the sources and grab the content directly from those instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, the additional data is not in the source from the first page. I can only assume there is a database request for each page, as clicking the JS links causes a page reload.

Comment: Well there still has to be a query string or something... Javascript has to send the message to the server *somehow*, when you find how it does it, just mimic that. And there **is** a way since Javascript can't talk directly to the server.

Comment: Find the definition of the show_page() function (which could well be in an external Javascript file) and mimic its behaviour. Your link is 404 for me. Also, the robots.txt at example.com seems to prohibit robots from the entire site so ensure your program respects the robots.txt file at the sites you want to scrape from

Comment: example.com is a time-honoured example URL. It is reserved as per http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606.txt. It's used for demonstrating rather than an actual site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emulating JS in PHP would be the tough route. Much easier to analyze the JS source and determine the URL target of the background AJAX operation. Should then be a fairly easy task to pull the entire data set into your PHP script by calling the URL and modifying args as needed.

Comment: It actually turned out to be an ASP.NET feature I was unfamiliar with, __doPostback. Once I read up on how that worked, I was able to mimic its behaviour using libCurl to submit POST data. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to try to reverse engineer the javascript function/ajax calls to their php script in order to do your own request to their server with the correct arguments.

You can use many firefox addons to make your life easier at reversing all of that (e.g. firebug by looking at network activity)